# Data extraction/reshape from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame - you can recreate the sample of it with the below code:

```
df = data.frame(M_id = c(rep(1000,8),rep(1001,8)), Day = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(1,4),rep(2,4)), Half_hr = rep(1:4,4) ,Val = c(0.25,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.35,0.5,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.45,0.6))
```

It looks like this:

```
>df : 

 M_id  Day  Half_hr     Val
 1000    1   1          0.25
 1000    1   2          0.1
 1000    1   3          0.2
 1000    1   4          0.4
 1000    2   1          0.3
 1000    2   2          0.6
 1000    2   3          0.35
 1000    2   4          0.5
 1001    1   1          0.15
 1001    1   2          0.2
 1001    1   3          0.3
 1001    1   4          0.5
 1001    2   1          0.4
 1001    2   2          0.7
 1001    2   3          0.45
 1001    2   4          0.6
```

Here , in each row, Val represents Value for that M_id for that Day in that Half_hr (Half_hr: 1,2 is hour 1 and 3,4 is hour 2 and so on). My actual data has so many Ids and Days and Val for 48 Half_hrs(for 24 hrs)

Now, I want to aggregate the data for each Half_hr into each hour for each M_id for each Day.

My output should look like this:

```
>df:

M_id    Day Hour_1  Hour_2
1000    1    0.35    0.6
1000    2    0.9     0.85
1001    1    0.35    0.8
1001    2    0.11    1.05
```

Example is M_id = 1000, Day = 1, Hour_1 = Val(Half_hr-1 + Half_hr-2) = 0.25+0.1 = 0.35. Similarly for Hour_2 = val(Half_hr-3 + Half_hr-4) = 0.2+0.4 = 0.6

I have done this using for loops and sqldf, but it was taking lots and lots of time.

I request an optimized code as the data I have to process has 1000 M_ids, each for 535 days and 48 Half_hrs for each day(24 Hrs data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`.  Create a grouping variable using `gl` after grouping by "M_id", "Day", then use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df)[order(M_id,Day, Half_hr)][,
         gr:=gl(.N, 2, .N) , .(M_id ,Day)][]
dcast(df1, M_id+Day~paste0("Hour_", gr), value.var="Val", sum)
#   M_id Day Hour1 Hour2
#1: 1000   1  0.35  0.60
#2: 1000   2  0.90  0.85
#3: 1001   1  0.35  0.80
#4: 1001   2  1.10  1.05
```

Comment: Does this assume `Half_hr` is ordered?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  I assumed that earlier, but after your comment `order`ed the data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in base R using [`transform()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html), [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html), and [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html):

```
reshape(aggregate(Val~.,transform(df,Hour=(Half_hr-1L)%/%2L+1L,Half_hr=NULL),sum),dir='w',idvar=c('M_id','Day'),timevar='Hour');
##   M_id Day Val.1 Val.2
## 1 1000   1  0.35  0.60
## 2 1001   1  0.35  0.80
## 3 1000   2  0.90  0.85
## 4 1001   2  1.10  1.05
```

Comment: Its working great too. But comparatively solution with data.table is fast for my data. Thank you so much.